# FB realime API is giving multiple responses

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time-data

I am using FB real time API to fetch real time data from a FB page. I have installed webhooks in my application and subscribed to feed, also made a POST request to /{page_id}/subscribed_apps end point to get real time updates. However, each time when a new data is added to my page FB realtime API is giving multiple responses.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You get several different updates send via one webhook request? That would be normal, Facebook can group updates that happen extremely close together. Or you get several requests for one and the same update? Then it would be likely that your server did not give a successful response in the required time; in that case Facebook sees the operation as failed, and will try again shortly after.

Comment: for the same update

Comment: The make sure your bot answers with status code `200 OK`, and quickly (if you do operations on your end that take a longer time to perform, then you need to find a way to send the 200 OK and close the connection, before you proceed.)